# Memory allocation in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1) tutorial as i am new to objective C.  I am trying to understand this initialization code

```
#import "RWTScaryBugDoc.h"
#import "RWTScaryBugData.h"
@implementation RWTScaryBugDoc
@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize thumbImage = _thumbImage;
@synthesize fullImage = _fullImage;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title rating:(float)rating thumbImage:(UIImage *)thumbImage fullImage:(UIImage *)fullImage {  
  if ((self = [super init])) {
  self.data = [[RWTScaryBugData alloc] initWithTitle:title rating:rating];
  self.thumbImage = thumbImage;
  self.fullImage = fullImage;
 }
return self;
}

@end
```

Here the class RWTScaryBugDoc contains three properties:data,thumbImage and fullImage. All are pointer objects. 
However on the initialization code memory is allocated only to the RWTScaryBugData and not to thumbImage and fullImage.
why is that ? 
How would caller know to allocate a memory for thumbImage and fullImage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor there has 4 parameters. Title, rating, thumb and full. The first two are used for the data property. The user should assume that they need to pass in all parameters already allocated/initialized.

Think about this, if you had a second constructor that took in data, thumb and full, you would need to alloc/init data yourself and then pass it in.

Comment: Yes i understand..if there was another initializer like you suggested with param as data,thumb and full, code would have been self.data=paramobject (assuming paramobject has already been allocated)

Comment: I did not look at the way it was actually called in the program !

Answer (score 1):

There is no `RWTScaryBugData` to assign directly; one has to be made using the `title` and `rating` parameters.  But there are parameters that can be (and are) directly assigned for thumbImage & fullImage.

The caller had to allocate space for *all* of the parameters passed; if she hadn't, she couldn't pass them.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted merely assigns the existing `UIImage` objects to the properties, so no allocation is necessary. The images are likely allocated before you call the initializer.

Also, FYI, explicit `@synthesize` statements are unnecessary in modern Objective-C unless you're overriding the accessors.